# grunt-rev and grunt-usemin with nested html files

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-usemin

I was under the impression that grunt-usemin with grunt-rev was able to step through a tree of html files and replace references to compiled assets with references to rev'd assets.

This is my grunt file and an example of what's going on:

https://gist.github.com/airtonix/8396336

Ideally what I'm aiming for is all the script and link tags in all the html be updated to point at the revved files (not just the html files in the root level)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue is that the regex usemin has only looks in the root level of each specified directory.

Try changing the relevant regex to look in sub-directories. For example,

```
'views/{,*/**/}*.html'
```